# SSO Auth flow w/ DocuSign_eSign gem: "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled."

Tags: ruby, docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign_eSign ruby gem [version 1.0.2](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client/releases/tag/v1.0.2) because version 2.0.0 does not handle JWT auth. The [eg-01-ruby-jwt example](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-ruby-jwt) provided by DocuSign uses v1.0.2 as well, so I just pinned this version in my Gemfile.

I am getting the following error when I attempt to make a call using the `DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopesApi.new#create_envelope` method:

```
docusign_esign-1.0.2/lib/docusign_esign/api_client.rb:66:in `call_api': Bad Request (DocuSign_eSign::ApiError)
```

For good measure, I walked through the code line by line to get a better idea of what was happening, and I ended up with this error:

```
irb(main):101:0> response.code
=> 401
irb(main):103:0> response.body
=> "{\r\n  \"errorCode\": \"PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED\",\r\n  \"message\": \"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified.\"\r\n}"
irb(main):104:0> response.status_message
=> "Unauthorized"
```

Here is the ruby code (minus logging/error handling) from my DocuSignWebClient where I trigger the call (`send_envelope`). This is where the auth happens:

```
TOKEN_REPLACEMENT_IN_SECONDS = 10.minutes.seconds
TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS = 1.hour.seconds

def initialize(options = {})
  @docusign_config = Padrino.config.docusign
  @api_client = DocuSignWebClient.setup_api_client
  @s3_client = options[:s3_client] || Aws::S3::Client.new(region: Padrino.config.aws.region)
  @token_expire_in = options[:token_expire_in] || 0
  @account_id = options[:account_id]
end

def self.setup_api_client
  configuration = DocuSign_eSign::Configuration.new
  DocuSign_eSign::ApiClient.new(configuration)
end

def send_envelope(details)
  authorize

  envelope = DocuSign::EnvelopeBuilder.new(details, @s3_client).build_envelope
  sender = DocuSign::EnvelopeSender.new(@api_client, @account_id)
  response = sender.send_envelope(envelope)
  update_document_status(details, response)
end

def authorize
  check_token
  @account_id ||= update_account_id
end

def check_token
  if no_token? || token_near_expiration?
    update_token
  end
end

def no_token?
  !@api_client.default_headers['Authorization']
end

def token_near_expiration?
  now = Time.now.to_f
  (now + TOKEN_REPLACEMENT_IN_SECONDS) > @token_expire_in
end

def update_token
  configure_jwt_authorization_flow
  @token_expire_in = Time.now.to_f + TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS
end

def configure_jwt_authorization_flow
  @api_client.configure_jwt_authorization_flow(@docusign_config[:private_key_file],
                                               @docusign_config[:auth_server],
                                               @docusign_config[:integrator_key],
                                               @docusign_config[:user_id],
                                               TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS)
end

def update_account_id
  account = fetch_account_info
  @api_client.config.host = account[:base_uri]
  account[:account_id]
end

def fetch_account_info
  response = DocuSignResponse.new(@api_client.call_api('GET', "https://#{@docusign_config[:auth_server]}/oauth/userinfo", return_type: 'Object'))

  if response.ok?
    response.data[:accounts].detect { |acct| acct[:is_default] }
  end
end
```

I *am* getting a token back from DocuSign after I go through the authorization flow, but it says that the token is not valid once I try to use it.

```
irb(main):033:0> account_id = client.authorize
=> "386...a24"
irb(main):036:0> client.api_client
=> #<DocuSign_eSign::ApiClient:0x00007ff6d243c8c8 @config=#<DocuSign_eSign::Configuration:0x00007ff6d243d2f0 @scheme="https", @host="demo.docusign.net", @base_path="/restapi", @api_key={}, @api_key_prefix={}, @timeout=0, @verify_ssl=true, @verify_ssl_host=true, @params_encoding=nil, @cert_file=nil, @key_file=nil, @debugging=false, @inject_format=false, @force_ending_format=false, @logger=#<Logger:0x00007ff6d243d110 @level=0, @progname=nil, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x00007ff6d243d098 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x00007ff6d243cfa8 @shift_period_suffix=nil, @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<IO:<STDOUT>>, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x00007ff6d243c8f0>, @mon_mutex_owner_object_id=70349033170900, @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0>>>, @user_agent="Swagger-Codegen/1.0.2/ruby", @default_headers={"Content-Type"=>"application/json", "User-Agent"=>"Swagger-Codegen/1.0.2/ruby", "Authorization"=>"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQkAAAABAAUABwAACzCudSXXSAgAAHP0D34l10gCABIJ3tlGgoJMvWi9_zzeFocVAAEAAAAYAAEAAAAFAAAADQAkAAAAZTVjOTIwMTItMWI0ZC00ZTgzLTgzNjYtNjgzNDQ0NjQyNjc0IwAkAAAAZTVjOTIwMTItMWI0ZC00ZTgzLTgzNjYtNjgzNDQ0NjQyNjc0EgABAAAABgAAAGp3dF9icg.yt_0QtjwAcL1dosfVuaNoKoM3Yzq9DK4MUf6lx3Sp5EYy0OdeSaKt6TgsAujUNQQoQH4e_IZFGtVXxBjFXzP2hh9EB2nsdwKAzi5EZJcOIp1wEfzKjEllUnOXOkEoUwcmHHCSN1j4LfNF8olRTDJnaSDB9A5TbumLURC_-FkttxHitFVpt39Fvl85VtSlIsQxU544SRjeJGJMl_BDwRmu0JrUSawc5LSUF9ET9SVTBGEjS_vZMz92hdiFM2x4qZqupeSXLrQ92bhzjEXHOH7kmKbE-iKDTH_TOln0rhhqLXq25yOTBJ_yUWqhvYaxpct9GRuPo6IIZCDDv0Of7k-xQ"}>
```

Does anything in that API instance look wrong? I can't figure out why my token is not working.

UPDATE: I re-attempted the same flow with a token using the [OAuth Token Generator](https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator) and that token also fails with the same error. Additionaly, I am able to send a token using the eg-01-ruby-jwt example code with the SAME EXACT inputs when calling DocuSign_eSign::ApiClient#configure_jwt_authorization_flow. The Envelopes API takes the API client and the account ID, which are identical upon inspection between the example code and my code (besides the auth token).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to use the token generator (https://developers.docusign.com/oauth-token-generator) and see if that token works for you. That would isolate the issue to obtaining the token.
2. Make sure in the sandbox admin, you configured your IK correctly, and that you use the exact same one.
3. You need an RSA key generated and make sure to use it for JWT.
4. Make sure you point to account-d.docusign.com and not account.docusign.com (so you use our developer sandbox and not production)

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

It's not working with the token generator token either, which tells me that the token is not the problem. I also am running through the eg-01-ruby-jwt code with the exact same inputs to receive a token, even getting the PK from the same location on my system, and that token does work. The account id passed to the Envelopes API is the same. Viewing the API client from both the example code and my code, the only difference is the token. 

Is there another non-token, non-account id reason that would cause a partner authentication error?

Comment: you are saying with token generator you're getting "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified"?
the only explanation for this might be that you are using production and not demo. Make sure your api calls go to demo.docusign.net and not www.docusign.net

Comment: I am positive that this is going to demo.docusign.net. Here is my ApiClient right before DocuSign_eSign::EnvelopesApi#create_envelope


#<DocuSign_eSign::ApiClient:0x00007faf69f97778 
  @config=#<DocuSign_eSign::Configuration:0x00007faf69f97f48 
    @scheme="https", 
    @host="demo.docusign.net", 
    @base_path="/restapi", 
    @api_key={}
    . . .
  >, 
  @user_agent="Swagger-Codegen/1.0.2/ruby", 
  @default_headers={
    "Content-Type"=>"application/json", 
    "User-Agent"=>"Swagger-Codegen/1.0.2/ruby", 
    "Authorization"=>"Bearer eyJ. . .GFg"
  }
>

Comment: ok, and you are using a token generated in the token generator and you are getting an error saying "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified"? you 100% sure of that?

Comment: Golly, I am not bright today. I must have messed something up in my line-by-line walkthrough of the code, and authorization was not the issue. It was a different issue that I didn't see because I wasn't logging the complete error message. Sorry for the trouble. Thanks for helping!

Comment: would you mind marking this question as answered? thanks!